# Liquid filtering array over a page property

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I've got a jekyll site with two pages (`page1.html` and `page2.html`), they both use the same layout. This layout print some information about some other pages in a given subdirectory. For example

- /_layouts/test.html

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

- /page1.html

```
---
layout: test
---
this page lists the title of my books...
```

This would print the title of every page in my site, but I want it to print only the title of pages in the subdirectory `/books`, so I would change the layout page to

```
{% for p in site.pages | where: 'dir','/books/' %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works fine, but I would like another page to use the same layout and list the content of my comics (that are inside `/comics` folder) instead of my books, so I would change the structure of my site in the following way:

- /_layouts/test.html

```
{% for p in site.pages | where: 'dir','/{{ page.directory_to_scan }}/' %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

- /page1.html

```
---
layout: test
directory_to_scan: books
---
this page lists the title of my books...
```

- /page2.html

```
---
layout: test
directory_to_scan: comics
---
this page lists the title of my comics...
```

However this does not work and no title at all is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've eventually solved by assembling the string before the loop, using the `append` filter.

```
{% assign d = '/' | append: page.directory_to_scan | append: '/' %}
{% for p in site.pages | where: 'dir',d %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix tags and filters (except for `assign`). Moreover, there's no need to enclose variables to a `filter` within double braces:

```
---
directory_to_scan: '/comics/'
---
```

And the layout would use:

```
{% assign my_pages = site.pages | where: 'dir', page.directory_to_scan %}
{% for p in my_pages %}
  {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as it's just a matter of moving the problem one step back: I may need to use that parameter in other places in my code and the slashes would make it difficult.